# Proof by contradicion

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, proof-writing, proof-explanation, computer-science

Let $x_1, x_2, . . . , x_n$ be $n$ real numbers. Let the average of $$x = \dfrac{x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_n}{n}$$ be their average. Prove that at least one of $x_1, x_2, \cdots , x_n$ is greater than or equal to $x$.

---

I am pretty sure this proof can be proved with contrapositive and I think I may know how to do that. However, I am wondering how you can do it with a contradiction. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated as I am new to discrete math. Thank you for all the comments in advance!

Comment: As with your [prior question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3752445/prove-that-the-following-proposition-is-true) getting somebody else to do your work for you is a bad way to learn anything.  Please edit your post to include your attempt.

Comment: If all of the $x_i$ are less than $x$ then what can you say about the sum of the $x_i$?

Comment: Suppose that all are strictly less than $x$.  Then in particular you have that $\frac{\color{red}{x_1}+x_2+\dots + x_n}{n} < \frac{\color{red}{x}+x_2+\dots+x_n}{n}$.  Do you see why?  Can you continue?

Comment: @lulu As I am a beginner at this course I have no idea where to start with proofs. I found a group of problems and I have been working on them for fun! Don't worry, I thoroughly think through all of the responses to come up with my own answer but thank you for being so concerned! <3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume that $x_i<x$ for every $i$.
Then:
$$x=\frac{x_1+...+x_n}{n}<\frac{x+...+x}{n}=\frac{nx}{n}=x $$
Which is a contradiction

Comment: Elegant, indeed.